# What is difference between .ipa with development provisioning and .ipa with adhoc distribution provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa

I looked on stack overflow there are many similar questions but could not understand exactly. As my knowledge there are three types provisioning profile -

1. Development provisioning profile
2. Ad hoc distribution provisioning profile
3. App store distribution provisioning profile

Development provisioning profile allows for testing and debugging.
Ad hoc distribution for beta testing without using Xcode.

**But my question is that** .ipa created for testing using development provisioning or using adhoc distribution provisioning, What is the difference in both ipa?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Development provisioning profile
```

the development provisioning profile is for testing your App on a device (iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch)

```
Ad hoc distribution provisioning profile
```

Adhoc testing is when you have completed development and want to distribute your app to multiple users for testing (your second question). Just create a distribution profile for adhoc testing and select all the device ids for which the profile is valid. In that case you will only need to send the .app file and .mobileprovision file to each user testing your app.

```
Details Desription:
```

If you'd like to install your software on several devices without using the App Store, you'll have to create an Ad Hoc distribution profile with the device ID numbers, and install that profile as well as the software, on all of the devices.

```
App store distribution provisioning profile
```

For submission of the app to app store, you  have to create a distribution mobile provisional file with the "App Store" option selected.

1.you want to test your App then use -    `Development provisioning profile`.

2.test multiple users without interaction with APP store then use -    `Ad hoc distribution provisioning profile`

2.multiple users  interaction with APP store then use -    `App store distribution provisioning profile`

Comment: Thanks @Sunny for answer, i understood whatever you said, still my question is same, what is the difference between ipa with development provisioning and ipa with adhoc distribution provisioning?

Comment: I just want to know the difference between both .ipa.... I hope you will be understand my question

Comment: As i meansioned in my answer for testing purpose you want to test your app between the 10 persons then you can use this one for getting the results in between those people means it works like testflight.

Comment: as my knowledge, both ipa can be send upto 100 testers. if i am wrong please tell me

Comment: is there any difference in both ipa or not?

Comment: i want to know one thing here ,do you know about TestFlight?

Comment: that one done based on Ad hoc distribution provisioning profile by using Development provisioning profile we can't do like this i think so.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27225/discussion-between-manju-gupta-and-sunny)

Comment: Here is good answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-provisionong-profile-and-a-ad-hoc-d