# Is it possible to remotely deploy an app update on test iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, devops, continuous-delivery

Im building a CI/CD system based on Gitlab CI, fastlane + Fabric (Firebase aka).
There are several types of provisioning, mostly described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-provisioning-profile-and-an-ad-hoc)

But the thing with which im struggling is how to automatically install updates for my test devices. Is it possible to automate it to 100% to skip the process when user have to check the beta app and click install update.

Comment: No you cant force the device to update. 
One thing you can do is "Notify Testers". that will trig a test flight notification for the beta update.

Comment: I've read somewhere that its possible with Macos Server, like MDM deployment...

Comment: MDM and TestFlight both are different. Still Mobile device management (MDM) automates pushing the build to the testers. it wont force the device to update it. Testers may wants to test different version. and forcing updates comes under user privacy. apple wont let the developer to do so.

Comment: @karthik can you imagine that in company we have one tester, who have 15 devices, on which he need make tests. Its does no make sense to him open each device and press "Instal update". If this option currently doesnt exists we should vote for writing to an Apple to enable this. If my post will collect 50 votes up, i will make an official letter from our company and will send it to Apple.

Comment: Is it possible, you use Testflight?

Comment: yes it is possible to use Testflight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to check `Apple Developer Enterprise Program` (299$ per year).

Look something like [Device management overview](https://help.apple.com/businessmanager/#/asm6a88f692e). For example [mobile device management (MDM)](https://help.apple.com/businessmanager/#/asm1c1be359d) can help you to solve your problem.