# Installing .ipa over the air does not open

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have signed my .ipa and I have tried to install it via diawi. The app got installed but it shows the app's icon in dark and does not open. I signed it with a iOS Certificate and when I try it from XCode and TestFlight it works perfectly! What could it be?

Comment: Is it a "ad-hoc" or "app-store" archive? Is the device you're installing onto registered in your account?  Just because it works through TestFlight, which is controlled and managed by Apple, doesn't mean it will work through other deployment methods

Comment: Why not use the "open beta" facility of TestFlight - You can post a link to your TestFlight build.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sign it with `AdHoc Provisioning Profile`.

You should also register the devices `UDID` in `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` in your Apple Developer Account.

## EDIT

Excerpt from Diawi Knowledge Base.

> #### A few things to check as a developer
>
> If you have uploaded an app to Diawi and can't install it on some of your devices, here are a few things to check:
>
> - device's UDID must be in the provisioning profile built into the app by xcode
> - device's UDID must not start with "fffffff..." (if it is, then it is fake)
> - you are building a Release version of your app
> - the device is not behind an enterprise firewall preventing app installation
>
> You may also try to drag&drop the app into iTunes and sync your device: it should install the app, otherwise it is not valid.

[Can't install an app on an iOS device? Things to check](https://www.diawi.com/knowledge-base/iOS/Cant-install-an-app-on-a-device-things-to-check)

[Distribute to registered devices (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev7ccaf4d3c)

[What is the difference between a Development Provisioning Profile and an Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-provisioning-profile-and-an-ad-hoc)

Comment: Doesn't you still need device UDID even using Diawi?

Comment: Apologies, yes, it seems that this is now the case.  It didn't used to be.

Comment: Thanks so much for your post! Every other post I found suggests using the "iOS App Store" option but my app didn't get the right icon and also didn't start with it (see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56988327/2016165)). With "Adhoc" it's working properly! :)