# Provisioning profile under code signing and provisioning profile for signing .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am so much confused provisioning profiles that comes under `Build Settings->Code Signing Identity` and provisioning profile used for signing .ipa file.

Should I always use same provisioning profile for both?

If I select one `Adhoc provisioning profile` to sign .ipa file then how does the provisioning profile under `Build Settings->Code Signing Identity` matters/affect the build?

I am more unclear about the provisioning profile under `Build Settings->Code Signing Identity`.

Lastly, if I set provisioning profile under `Build Settings->Code Signing Identity` to `Distribution profile` and sign `.ipa` with `Adhoc provisioning profile` then should it work?

Answer (score 0):

> If I select one Adhoc provisioning profile to sign .ipa file then how
>   does the provisioning profile under Build Settings->Code Signing
>   Identity matters/affect the build?

I think there is no difference how to sign the app: during the build process from Build Settings->Code Signing Identity or after building when you create the .ipa file. In case you re-sign the app under creating the .ipa, you will rewrite the information in app packatge to use new provision profile so the previous sign action will be no longer actual.

> Lastly, if I set provisioning profile under Build Settings->Code
>   Signing Identity to Distribution profile and sign .ipa with Adhoc
>   provisioning profile then should it work?

Thus yes, it should work (If correctly understand the question). However, there are some limitations of Development/Distribution profiles. Maybe, following links will be helpful:

[What is the difference between a development provisionong profile and a ad hoc distribution profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506535/what-is-the-difference-between-a-development-provisionong-profile-and-a-ad-hoc-d)

[What is difference between .ipa with development provisioning and .ipa with adhoc distribution provisioning profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15716026/what-is-difference-between-ipa-with-development-provisioning-and-ipa-with-adho)

[iOS Developer Builds vs Distribution Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241552/ios-developer-builds-vs-distribution-builds)